# Java SSE Server with com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer

Tags: java, http, java-11

How can implement SSE Server with `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer`
I wrote simple `HttpHandler` like this for testing connection:

```
public class SseResource implements HttpHandler {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException {
        Headers responseHeaders = exchange.getResponseHeaders();
        responseHeaders.add("Content-Type", "text/event-stream");
        responseHeaders.add("Connection", "keep-alive");
        responseHeaders.add("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");
        responseHeaders.add("X-Powered-By", "Native Application Server");

        exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, responseHeaders.size());
        OutputStream writer = exchange.getResponseBody();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            writer.write("event: count\n".getBytes()); // <-- Connection Closed at this line 
            writer.write(("data: " + i + "\n").getBytes());
            writer.write("\n\n".getBytes());
            writer.flush();
            sleep();
        }

        writer.close();
    }


    public static void sleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Does not work.
I test connection with Linux `curl` command:

```
curl -Ni http://localhost:8080/stream

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
X-powered-by: Native Application Server
Date: Thu, 10 Jun 2021 05:27:56 GMT
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Content-type: text/event-stream
Content-length: 4

curl: (18) transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

Did I misunderstand about SSE server? or does my code have a problem?

Comment: _exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, responseHeaders.size());_ What about using the response size instead if the number of headers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

response size should be zero .
I compare my response headers with result of this project : https://github.com/enkot/SSE-Fake-Server

```
exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);
```

Comment: Yes - and you shouldn't specify "Transfer-encoding: chunked" in your custom response headers: the HttpServer does that for you. More specifically, if you call:
sendResponseHeaders(code, 0) the server will transmit the response body using chunked encoding. If you supply a <length> (instead of 0) the server will send the response without transfer encoding - but with "Content-Length: <length>". See https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/jdk.httpserver/com/sun/net/httpserver/HttpExchange.html#sendResponseHeaders(int,long)